# Micronaut WebSocketClient

Tags: websocket, micronaut

Im relatively new to micronaut and its concepts, tho I found some examples (also in the micronaut documentation) where a WebsocketClient was implemented by annotation a class with `@ClientWebsocket`and implementing AutoCloseable. This would be then injected into a `WebsocketClient.class` field which would be annnotated with `@Client(URI)`.

However when i try to replicate the exact same thing micronaut always tells me is would not find any matching `@Bean`s for the field to inject. (Which for me makes sense beacues the implementation annotated with `@ClientWebsocket` isnt actually a `WebsocketClient.class`)

```java
@Bean
public class Session {

    @Client("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json")
    WebSocketClient webSocketClient;

    Session(WebSocketClient webSocketClient) {
        this.webSocketClient = webSocketClient;
        Publisher<TestWebSocketClient> connect = this.webSocketClient.connect(TestWebSocketClient.class, "wss://api.discord.gg/api/v6/gateway");
        TestWebSocketClient chatClientWebSocket = Flowable.fromPublisher(connect).blockingFirst();
    }
}
```

```java
@Bean
@ClientWebSocket
public abstract class TestWebSocketClient implements AutoCloseable {

    private WebSocketSession session;
    private CloseReason lastReason;
    private Throwable lastError;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(WebSocketSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("message = " + message);
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        this.lastError = error;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(CloseReason closeReason) {
        this.lastReason = closeReason;
    }

    public void send(String message){
        session.send(message);
    }

    public Throwable getLastError() {
        return lastError;
    }

    public CloseReason getLastReason() {
        return lastReason;
    }

    public WebSocketSession getSession() {
        return session;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void close() {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

```
Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketClient] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new Session(WebSocketClient webSocketClient) --> new Session([WebSocketClient webSocketClient])
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.resolveBean(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1955)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.getBeanForConstructorArgument(AbstractInitializableBeanDefinition.java:1189)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I post my guess as an answer, cause its easier to add some code, than in a comment.
To me it seems that you mix field and constructor injection.
So you have to choose one. I prefer always constructor injection.

If you use constructor injection, you also have to add the @Client annoation on the constructor see https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-http-client-gradle-java.html low level client as an example.
So try to add the annotation to the constructor i hope that solves your issue.

```
@Bean
public class Session {

    
    WebSocketClient webSocketClient;

    Session(@Client("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json") WebSocketClient webSocketClient) {
        this.webSocketClient = webSocketClient;
        Publisher<TestWebSocketClient> connect = this.webSocketClient.connect(TestWebSocketClient.class, "wss://api.discord.gg/api/v6/gateway");
        TestWebSocketClient chatClientWebSocket = Flowable.fromPublisher(connect).blockingFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes your right with mixing up where to put the annotation. Unfortunately i still get the same error. `Message: No bean of type [io.micronaut.websocket.WebSocketClient] exists. `